# MIN and MAX SQL function

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, min

I have an existing problem and I don't know my way around it.

I have a table that contains below records.

[image]

What I would like to be returned is this:

[image: Result]

Basically what I need to be returned is the Documentid and Destination of a record with minimum value for Rank column, but for result column Company the one needed to be returned should be the one with maximum Rank.

I can only able to use one function but i'm struggling to create/use MIN and MAX function at the same time to produce the result.

Sample code

```
Select 
    documentid, 
    destination, 
    Company 
from Table1 
INNER JOIN (Select Destination, MIN(Rank) AS MINRank from Table1 group by Destination) mindest 
    ON mindest.destination = table1.destination
```

Comment: What have you tried? A code sample would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry for not providing my sample code, as the above one is just a dummy data, my situation is pretty similar to that but the data is confidential so I really can't share what I have done to the actual data.

But yes I will try to provide one for the above.

Comment: Select documentid, destination, Company from Table1
INNER JOIN
(Select Destination, MIN(Rank) AS MINRank from Table1
group by Destination) mindest ON mindest.destination = table1.destination





Here's my sample code to the above one.

Comment: Your Westeros is just a count of two then why result of company become 3?

Comment: Show a clear sample data here and a clear expected result.

Comment: I think max rank means 1 and min rank min 3.

Answer (score 1):

please try this...

```
select documentid, destination,
 (select max(Rank) from table1) [Company]
 from Table1
  where Rank = (select min(Rank) from table1)
```

Comment: Thank you. what if instead of Table1, I just have a resulting select set. 
I tried this but didn't work.

Comment: `select documentid, destination,
 (select max(Rank) from table1) [Company]
 from (SELECT .... ) AS Table1
  where Rank = (select min(Rank) from table1)`

Comment: Create a view with your select and replace all table1 with your view

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this?

```
DECLARE @tb TABLE(Documentid INT,[Rank] INT  ,Destination VARCHAR(10),Company VARCHAR(10))
INSERT @tb
SELECT 12393,1,'Westeros','CompanyA' UNION ALL
SELECT 12394,2,'Westeros','CompanyB' UNION ALL
SELECT 12395,3,'Essos','CompanyC' 
SELECT t.Documentid,t.Destination,t.MaxRank AS Company FROM (
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY [Rank]) AS Seq,MAX([Rank])OVER() AS MaxRank FROM @tb
) AS t WHERE t.seq=1
```

```
Documentid  Destination Company
----------- ----------- -----------
12393       Westeros    3
```